# Why are the components of a standard d-dimensional Wiener process independent and not of a non-standard?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

What I mean by a standard d-dimensional Wiener process is a vector-valued stochastic process $W_t = (W^{(1)}_t, W^{(2)}_t, ..,W^{(d)}_t)$ whose components are standard one-dimensional Wiener processes. During our lecture the professor told us that these components are only independent if the components are different standard Wiener processes, hence with $\sigma^2 = 1$. Why is this not the case for Wiener processes with any $\sigma^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this statement: "these components are only independent if the components are standard Wiener processes." If we let $W_t^{(1)}$ denote a standard Wiener process, and we define a $d$-dimensional vector by repeating this same Wiener process in each component, i.e. $W_t = (W_t^{(1)}, W_t^{(1)}, \dotsc, W_t^{(1)})$, then each component is the (same) one-dimensional Wiener process, but the components are not independent (because they are identical!).

Comment: Thank you, you are right they indeed need to be different standard Wiener processes @nahp

Comment: Sorry, I got confused; above, I argued that if a $d$-dimensional process has components equal to one-dimensional Wiener processes, it need not have independent components. However, to return to your statement, it is also true that the components could be independent Wiener processes but not all components need to be standard. For example, if $W_t^{(1)}$ and $W_t^{(2)}$ are two independent standard Wiener processes, then the components of $(W_t^{(1)}, 3 W_t^{(2)})$ are independent Wiener processes, but the second component has $\sigma^2 = 9$.

Comment: Ah yes that is true, thank you. Maybe I misunderstood my professor @nahp